# Infinite scrolling results on Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using Backpack for Laravel (Backpack v4.1 and Laravel 8). The default view is pagination and I'd like to get infinite scrolling instead of pagination. I can't find any settings that handle this, I believe DataTables (the underlying library) has support for it. But I'm not sure how to do it within the Backpack system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible in DataTables, it should be possible in Backpack.

#### Solution 1 - edit the `datatables_logic` blade file

You can [publish the view](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-how-to#publish-a-column-field-filter-button-and-modify-it) using `php artisan backpack:publish crud/inc/datatables_logic`. This will place a copy of it in your `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/inc/datatables_logic.blade.php` so you can edit it as you like.

In Backpack 4.1 [the file looks like this](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/crud/inc/datatables_logic.blade.php). It's pretty messy, but it should allow you to add a DataTables extension or modify it to your liking.

Just note that once that file is published, Backpack will use your file, instead of the one in the package. So you won't be getting any updates on that one file when you do `composer update`.

#### Solution 2 - create a custom operation

Alternatively, if you don't need all the bells & whistles of the List operation (filters, columns, pagination, export, search), you can [create a custom operation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations#creating-a-custom-operation-1), for example `InfiniteList`. That will allow you to show *exactly* what you want, *exactly* how you want it.

---

If I were you, I'd go with the second solution and build something from scratch. You'd be in complete control over what happens, you wouldn't rely on a DataTables extension and you wouldn't have to fix any conflicts between DataTables extensions.